# Erlang histogram summing 2 maps

Tags: dictionary, sum, erlang, histogram

How do you create a histogram sum of two dicts in erlang?  Example if you have 2 dicts:

```
{a: 1, c: 4, d:7} and {a:5, b:8, d:1}
```

The sum would be:

```
{a:6, b:8, c:4, d:8}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume your dicts are bound to `A` and `B` variables respectevily, then:

```
Result = dict:merge(fun (_Key, V1, V2) -> V1 + V2 end, A, B)
```